# How can I add events correctly for different ImageTargets in Vuforia?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

[image]

You can see that I have two targets and two 3D objects that overlay them every time they are detected.

Now I want to add separate events (onFound, onLost) for both targets.

What is the best way to do this ? Should I add a separate script to each target ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could checkout [UnityEvent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) (these are e.g. like the `onClick` of buttons).

So on each image target you could have e.g.

```c#
public class CustomImageTarget : DefaultTrackableEventHandler
{
    public UnityEvent onFound;
    public UnityEvent onLost;

    protected override void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        // if you also want the default behaviour in this
        // (enables Renderers, Colliders and Canvas)
        // base.OnTrackingFound();

        onFound.Invoke();
    }

    protected override void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        // if you also want the default behaviour in this
        // (Disables Renderers, Colliders and Canvas)
        // base.OnTrackingLost();

        onLost.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Then you can either attach a reaction in the Inspector via Drag&Drop (like you would do with the `onClick` of a `Button` component)

Or you can add listeners in a script on runtime by doing

```c#
aCustomImageTatgetReference.onFound.AddListener(/* ... */);
```

Comment: I was here to share a solution and found a better one!!!! Thanks dude!!! My solution involved changing code in `DefaultTrackableEventHandler`... this is so much cleaner.

Comment: @Horothenic hey man since you are working on something similar would you mind sharing your code with me ? on github maybe ?

Comment: Sorry I had it a bit wrong: you have to inherit from `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` .. otherwise you would have to implement the whole `OnTrackableStateChanged` logic on your own. I updated the answer

Comment: @derHugo And have 2 of these attached at each ImageTarget? Should I create the scripts in a folder or let Unity decide by adding a component (new Script) ?

Comment: One Scripts per target. And it doesn't matter .. if "Unity decides" all your new scripts are placed in the `Assets` root folder. It is only important that it is not placed in one of the reserved folders like `Editor` or `PlugIns`

Comment: My solution was changing the 'DefaultTrackableEventHandler' for the code to GetComponent the component I wanted XD... so not cool